# How do I enable remote desktop of the GUI?

Tags: centos, remote-desktop

I can ssh into my machine.  I want to be able to login to the GUI to do dev work.  I  went go Applications > System Tools > settings > Sharing > and I have Remote login and Screen Sharing both on.  I tried to connect to the CentOS box from my Mac OSX box using VNC Viewer.   For the server I used my internal IP:  192.x.x.x.

"The connection was refused by the host computer".

I am actively logged into the unix machine with a non-admin account.

How do I get going?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, asides from the obvious security holes that VNC causes (seriously, key stokes are sent **unencrypted** so anyone in the middle can grab a **password**), you're going to want to make sure that you have to adjust your firewall which is in:

Applications -> Firewall -> Enter your root password -> Services -> vnc-server

Enable it, quit, and make sure that vnc is started and enabled.

You can always check from your mac machine by using `nmap` against it.

Comment: Is there a more secure alternative for GUI access?  (not ssh, I need GUI).

Comment: As loshad mentioned you can use VNC through SSH but you'll need to do some funky things to get that workings. I'd just recommend using `ssh -X user@host`. If you need eclipse or firefox then you would just type eclipse from the command line and that GUI will be tunneled.

Comment: X11 is the type of tool I was looking for.  Mac: http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/ or Windows: http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/.  Once you have X11 you can run a "remote desktop" like session through ssh.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey I normally use [cygwin](http://cygwin.com/), but anything that will emulate an X11 server will do

Answer (score 2):

Also you may log in to your machine using ssh -X -Y login@hostname (if allowed by sshd settings) and start vncviewer on a remote machine.